# Как добавлять новые input через js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Есть ViewModel:

```
    public class ProductCreateViewModel
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

    public double ProductPrice { get; set; }

    public List<string> ImagesUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Модель Images хранит в себе ProductId и ImageUrl.
Как сделать так чтобы для списка Images постоянно добавлялись новые инпуты в которые мы вставляем ссылки на изображения?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос, что здесь значит постоянно добавлялись новые инпуты? Могу предложить создать форму для ссылки и отправлять post  запрос на сохранение в БД

Comment: @АлексейКлещевников генерится несколько инпутов для вставки ссылок в них. Если все они заполнены - генерим новый инпут для ещё одной ссылки.

Comment: тогда такой вопрос больше не по asp.net mvc, а javascript:)

Comment: @АлексейКлещевников нашел похожее решение https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/766214/List-Model-Binding-in-MVC

Comment: полезная ссылка буду иметь ввиду, предлагаю вам оформить ответ, чтобы этот вопрос считался решенным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На такой вопрос уже отвечали, загляните https://toster.ru/q/320062

Comment: Да, инпуты генерятся. Но как их связать с List в модели?